# Hash an XML file Using Python for Zatca

Tags: python

Zatca required to hashing the XML file (based on UBL 2.1) and I have their SDK file for developer, and I tried to hash the XML file using Python and hash same XML using SDK but the result is not the same.

As mentioned by ZATCA documentations, the steps for hashing the XML file are:

```
1. Remove the
<Invoice><ext:UBLExtensi
ons/> block
2. Remove the
<invoice><cac:Additional
DocumentReference/>
block where <cbc:ID/> =
QR
3. Remove the
<invoice><cac:Signature/>
block
4. Canonicalize the Invoice
using the C14N11
standard
5. Hash the resulting string
using SHA256 to a binary
object
6. Base64 encode the binary
object to generate the
digest value
```

The below code in python:

```
f = open("invoice_00045.xml", "r")
    st =f.read()
    # Canonicalize
    xmldsig = chilkat2.XmlDSig()
    canonXml = xmldsig.CanonicalizeXml(st,"C14N",False)
    encoded_str = canonXml.encode()
    # create sha3-256 hash objects
    obj_sha3_256 = hashlib.sha256(encoded_str)
    hashed = obj_sha3_256.hexdigest()
    # print in hexadecimal
    encoded_base64_bytes = b64encode(bytes.fromhex(hashed)).decode()
```

Python Output:
R0J8+RX8HHdTiyjJSwstbKetQnI14KY1eugsBKsNXao=

SDK Output:
LzcxChG74WtAw3jO3WQz9b+P44J0ivT/N97PLBELxYU=

Comment: Instead of calling .hexdigest() try calling digest() method

Comment: Did Sai's comment solve your issue?